# Is the raw depth data from the Kinect 2 completely unfiltered?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

As the title says, is the raw data really raw or does the Kinect apply some sort of filtering (median, bilateral etc.) to reduce the noise? I am comparing the data with other non consumer ToF cameras and it seems that the raw values from the Kinect 2 are pretty smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, some filters are applied.

But Microsoft doesn't publish any information about what's going on inside their Kinect SDK/hardware, so we can only guess.

The best information about this comes from [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/), the open source driver for Kinect v2. One of the developers said:

> [libfreenect's] current depth processing code [...] is doing the same things as the shader shipped with the K4W2 Preview SDK (might have changed in the meantime). The **bilateral filter** is applied to the complex valued images before computing the amplitude/phase(depth). Its only aware of intensity edges in these images. The **"edge-aware" filter** basically tries to filter the **flying pixels** at the object boundaries by calculating some statistics in a local neighborhood. Both filters can be disabled in libfreenect2.

(emphasis mine, [Source](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/134#issuecomment-70991519))

Of course we don't know if there's anything else going on or if something changed in the release version of the Microsoft SDK.

Btw. here's a recent paper comparing some current ToF sensors:

> [A Comparative Error Analysis of Current Time-of-Flight Sensors - Peter Fürsattel et al.](https://www5.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/Forschung/Publikationen/2016/Fuersattel16-CEA.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer.